# fav_services() not working codition not wokring

Tags: php

I'm trying to get favorites data

```
public function fav_services(){
  $logged = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `service_favorites`  JOIN service ON service.sid = service_favorites.s_id WHERE uid = '$logged'";
  return $this->db->query($query);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake. Should have used LEFT join.

```
public function fav_services(){
   $logged = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `service_favorites` LEFT JOIN service ON service.sid = service_favorites.s_id WHERE uid = '$logged'";
   return $this->db->query($query);   
}
```